# Travis-CI Android tests with Gradle keep timing out

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

I'm trying to build & test my project on Travis CI. It keeps showing me same repetitive output every time on all my repositories.

Here is my travis.yml https://github.com/carts-uiet/cartsbusboarding/blob/master/.travis.yml

```
language: android
    android:
    components:
    # Uncomment the lines below if you want to
    # use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
    # - platform-tools
    # - tools
    # The BuildTools version used by your project
    - build-tools-21.0.0
    # The SDK version used to compile your project
    - android-21
    # Additional components
    - add-on
    - extra
    # Specify at least one system image,
    # if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-21
    # Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
    before_script:
    - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
    - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
    - android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

Here is one such build https://travis-ci.org/carts-uiet/cartsbusboarding/builds/39447907

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_60
before_script.1
3.53s$ echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
Android 5.0 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]Created AVD 'test' based on Android 5.0, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
with the following hardware config:
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.ramSize=512
vm.heapSize=48
before_script.2
0.01s
$ emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
$ android-wait-for-emulator
Failed to Initialize backend EGL display
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
error: device offline
error: device offline
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device offline
error: device offline
running
running
running
running
running
running
```

All these builds time-out.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated response:** VM images already include fixed android-wait-for-emulator script and android SDK tools version 24.0.0 by default solving this issue. I deleted my outdated response and workaround.

[Build Environment Updates - 2014-12-09](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/157#issuecomment-66310281)

Comment: You are welcome, solution coming soon https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/112780/

Comment: The new android-wait-for-emulator has been fixed, you can try to use it. I update the response.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the best alternative to get the latest version of the script:

I added this to my before script:

```
# Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - curl http://is.gd/android_wait_for_emulator > android-wait-for-emulator
  - chmod u+x android-wait-for-emulator
  - ./android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

The url points to the latest script available on github.

Hope that helps . . .

Answer (score 1):

You need to instruct your travis build to actually run unit tests:

```
# run tests  against the emulator
- ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
# run tests  against the JVM
- ./gradlew test
```