# com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[test(AVD) - 5.0] FAILED

Tags: android, testing, gradle, travis-ci

i have try my best to test my android project with gradle on, but failed.
    can you help me with it?Thank you.
    This is my project:
https://github.com/SnowdreamFramework/android-log
   and i provide my error log with the attachment.

```
[0K$ echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
Android 5.0 is a basic Android platform.
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile [no]Created AVD 'test' based on Android 5.0, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
with the following hardware config:
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.ramSize=512
vm.heapSize=48
travis_time:end:0d68df50:start=1416651329874810477,finish=1416651333337412612,duration=3462602135
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_script.4
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_script.5
[0Ktravis_time:start:15d80c70
[0K$ emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
travis_time:end:15d80c70:start=1416651333347425441,finish=1416651333353869405,duration=6443964
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_script.5
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_script.6
[0Ktravis_time:start:01e4ff4d
[0K$ android-wait-for-emulator
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Waiting for emulator to start
Failed to Initialize backend EGL display
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Waiting for emulator to start
Emulator is ready
travis_time:end:01e4ff4d:start=1416651333362333914,finish=1416651367641918931,duration=34279585017
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_script.6
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_script.7
[0Ktravis_time:start:1f99871a
[0K$ adb shell input keyevent 82 &
travis_time:end:1f99871a:start=1416651367652665093,finish=1416651367659437822,duration=6772729
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_script.7
[0Ktravis_time:start:0e5eb826
[0K$ TERM=dumb gradle build connectedCheck
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.13.3/gradle-0.13.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/4.11/proguard-gradle-4.11.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-parent/4.11/proguard-parent-4.11.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/23.1.3/lint-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.13.3/builder-0.13.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/4.11/proguard-base-4.11.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/23.1.3/lint-checks-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.2.2/ecj-4.2.2.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/23.1.3/ddmlib-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/0.13.3/builder-model-0.13.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/23.1.3/sdk-common-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/23.1.3/manifest-merger-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/0.13.3/builder-test-api-0.13.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/common/23.1.3/common-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/23.1.3/sdklib-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/23.1.3/lint-api-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/4.0/asm-analysis-4.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/4.0/asm-parent-4.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.3/ow2-1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kxml2/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/15.0/guava-15.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava-parent/15.0/guava-parent-15.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/23.1.3/layoutlib-api-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/httpclient-4.1.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1.1/httpcomponents-client-4.1.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/4.1.1/project-4.1.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1/httpcomponents-client-4.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/23.1.3/dvlib-23.1.3.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/33/commons-parent-33.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.0/asm-4.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.2/lombok-ast-0.2.2.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.0/asm-tree-4.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.1/httpcomponents-core-4.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-parent-11.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.13.3/gradle-0.13.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/4.11/proguard-gradle-4.11.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/23.1.3/lint-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.13.3/builder-0.13.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/4.11/proguard-base-4.11.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/23.1.3/lint-checks-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.2.2/ecj-4.2.2.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/23.1.3/ddmlib-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/0.13.3/builder-model-0.13.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/23.1.3/sdk-common-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/23.1.3/manifest-merger-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/0.13.3/builder-test-api-0.13.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/common/23.1.3/common-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/23.1.3/sdklib-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/23.1.3/lint-api-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/4.0/asm-analysis-4.0.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/15.0/guava-15.0.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/23.1.3/layoutlib-api-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/23.1.3/dvlib-23.1.3.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.0/asm-4.0.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.2/lombok-ast-0.2.2.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.0/asm-tree-4.0.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar
Sonatype SNAPSHOT BUILD
GITHUB SNAPSHOT BUILD
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/22/commons-parent-22.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
:lib:androidJavadocsJar
:lib:compileLint
:lib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:lib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:lib:preBuild
:lib:preReleaseBuild
:lib:checkReleaseManifest
:lib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:lib:compileReleaseAidl
:lib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:lib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:lib:mergeReleaseAssets
:lib:generateReleaseResValues
:lib:generateReleaseResources
:lib:packageReleaseResources
:lib:processReleaseManifest
:lib:processReleaseResources
:lib:generateReleaseSources
:lib:compileReleaseJava
:lib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageReleaseJar
:lib:compileReleaseNdk
:lib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:lib:bundleRelease
:lib:assembleRelease
:lib:androidReleaseJar
:lib:androidSourcesJar
:lib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:lib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:lib:preDebugBuild
:lib:checkDebugManifest
:lib:prepareDebugDependencies
:lib:compileDebugAidl
:lib:compileDebugRenderscript
:lib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:lib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:lib:mergeDebugAssets
:lib:generateDebugResValues
:lib:generateDebugResources
:lib:packageDebugResources
:lib:processDebugManifest
:lib:processDebugResources
:lib:generateDebugSources
:lib:compileDebugJava
:lib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageDebugJar
:lib:compileDebugNdk
:lib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:lib:bundleDebug
:lib:assembleDebug
:lib:signArchives
:lib:assemble
:lib:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 7 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 7 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/home/travis/build/SnowdreamFramework/android-log/lib/build/outputs/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to /home/travis/build/SnowdreamFramework/android-log/lib/build/outputs/lint-results.xml
:lib:check
:lib:build
:lib:compileDebugTestNdk
:lib:preDebugTestBuild
:lib:prepareDebugTestDependencies
:lib:compileDebugTestAidl
:lib:processDebugTestManifest
:lib:compileDebugTestRenderscript
:lib:generateDebugTestBuildConfig
:lib:generateDebugTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:lib:mergeDebugTestAssets
:lib:generateDebugTestResValues
:lib:generateDebugTestResources
:lib:mergeDebugTestResources
:lib:processDebugTestResources
:lib:generateDebugTestSources
:lib:compileDebugTestJava
:lib:preDexDebugTest
:lib:dexDebugTest
:lib:processDebugTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:lib:validateDebugSigning
:lib:packageDebugTest
:lib:assembleDebugTest
:lib:connectedAndroidTest
Tests on test(AVD) - 5.0 failed: No test results

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[test(AVD) - 5.0] [31mFAILED [0m
No tests found.
:lib:connectedAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lib:connectedAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/travis/build/SnowdreamFramework/android-log/lib/build/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 23.514 secs
travis_time:end:0e5eb826:start=1416651367667280733,finish=1416651451763431060,duration=84096150327
[0K
[31;1mThe command "TERM=dumb gradle build connectedCheck" exited with 1.[0m

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Updated response:** VM images already include fixed android-wait-for-emulator script and android SDK tools version 24.0.0 by default solving other issues.

[Build Environment Updates - 2014-12-09](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/157#issuecomment-66310281)

### Brief response:

Bugged script causes your emulator don't be ready for your tests and your app is not installed due a timeout, so there are no tests performed and the build fails as a new behavior added to  alert you about issues as this.

---

### Explanation:

You are running on the background an outdated `android-wait-for-emulator` script that exits when the ADB server is `running` but your emulator is not fully booted (requires `stopped` state)  (See **point 7**).

As your emulator is not ready and exists a two minutes `INSTALL_TIMEOUT`, your build fails with an `InstallException` caused by `ShellCommandUnresponsiveException` (See **point 4**).

You are trying to test an app running one command without `--debug` information, you could try my suggestion on comments and use `gradle installDebug --debug` and split the build (See **point 2**).

As you are using Travis CI build server, You need add logcat and connectedDevice logs to their output. I offer you one option that works but can be improved. Use your app module `MOD_NAME=lib` (See **point 5**).

You need manage concurrency, try to avoid create the AVD while you download/install gradle, etc. You can use `install: true` if you don't need it but I recommend you use it to install gradle (See **point 3**).

It's possible ignore this failure when you don't need test the app on an emulator or you still have no tests but Google added this feature to detect issues and I don't recommend that you disable it (See **point 1**).

You can disable run test from conflictive dependencies but is not your problem, ignore it now (See **point 6**).

I deleted **points 8 and 9** about testing samples and sdcard usage because my response is too long but you use the sdcard on your lib and it's possible you need define another location for your sdcard, I don't know it.

Solving the emulator issue it's possible that sometimes you see the same error or other random issues as error core 137 (See **point 10**).

You can try to reload the job, change your configuration, use `echo` so server knows your build is not failing, use `adb wait-for-device`, check `adb device` state, increase `ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT` etc.

If you follow the other points, mainly to use another script and read the logs, I'm sure you'll detect and solve all the issues.

---

### First response edited:

I didn't remember the real reason and you didn't share enough debug information but i solved this issue on my tests a weeks ago. I was not sure because I saved it as:

```
  # com.android.ddmlib.InstallException. connectedAndroidTest run tests failed, (exceed timeout).
  # @-- Issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69735  (now optimize/reload job).
  # @-- 144.6 --@ Solution: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/112780/ (inc. install time).
```

Now that i think I know the solution I add comments to my previous response:

---

**Point 1** was a work around I used when i didn't know the reason, you don't need it now. We'll solve it.

1. You can add this to your build.gradle on all the tested modules to ignore this failure by now.

> ```
> project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
>     connectedAndroidTest {
>         ignoreFailures = true
>     }
> }
> ```

---

**Point 2** was another work around that is useful for split the build and avoid the problem if you don't need test.
Your real problem is about install your app on an emulator that is not ready and seems a testing issue.

2. Or use `gradle build` or `gradle assembleDebug assembleDebugTest`.

> assemble: The task to assemble the output(s) of the project
>
> check: The task to run all the checks.
>
> connectedCheck: Runs checks that requires a connected device or
>   emulator.
>
> build: This task does both assemble and check
>
> Note that build does not depend on deviceCheck, or connectedCheck.

See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks

> checks requiring a connected device are launched with the anchor task
>   called connectedCheck.
>
> This depends on the task androidTest and therefore will run it.  This
>   task does the following:
>
> - Ensure the app and the test app are built (depending on assembleDebug and assembleTest)
> - install both apps
> - run the tests
> - uninstall both apps.

See  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-tests

---

**Point 3** was the last point adapted to Travis Yaml case. I always override install stage so I'm not sure if they currently execute `gradle assemble` by default using their gradle v2.0 but the best you can do is to be sure nothing is executed without you know it and use `install: true`.

3. Travis sample using `./gradlew build` as the script. Or `./gradle build` if you are not using gradle wrapper. Really you have gradle wrapper and use wget, i don't understand it.

> ```
> install:
>   # Check install section: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#install
>   # If you'd like to skip the install stage entirely, set it to true and nothing will be run.
>   - true
>
> script:
>   # By default Travis-ci executes './gradlew build connectedCheck' if no 'script:' section found.
>   - ./gradlew build
> ```

See [Travis CI skip tests (Gradle Android project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800944)

---

**Point 4** is the issue/feature added by Google a weeks ago that helps that you know something is wrong. If you use `--debug` you can read the reason that no test are performed. An InstallException caused by ShellCommandUnresponsiveException.

> When running connectedCheck and no tests are found, it should be
>   considered a failure. This will allow detecting issue where a bad setup leads to not running any existing tests. (Xavier Ducrohet)

4. > When running connectedCheck and no tests are found, it should be
   >   considered a failure. The absence of tests is very different than
   >   having tests and not having them run. This feature is for the latter
   >   case (Jake Wharton)

See issue: [76249: Gradle should break if no tests are run](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76249)

See feature: [108410: Running tests with no test found will now break the build.](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/108410/)

---

**Point 5** was my first "bash/yaml/ruby script" trying to find the response. Really needs be improved, I only knew that is parsed as Yaml, I used Bash manual and that is used by Ruby code. I added ' ' because looks ugly on github, i omitted it here. `For` line is from [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/master/paper/lib/web-animations-js/.travis.yml)

I found it, and today I have found the build with after_failure logs about this: [See lines 5073, 5161, 5184](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/jobs/40613843#L5184)

5. You can use after_failure section to read logcat and test outputs, perhaps you find the real problem if you already have tests and the problem is another. I think an installation issue due to emulator no ready or other CI related issues. You say the app works on your personal machine.

> ```
> before_script:   
>   # - echo 'LOGCAT'   
>   # Check logcat debug output: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html
>   # Check debugging log: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html
>   # Comment the lines belows to debug output and redirect it to a file. Custom tags for your app.
>   - adb -e logcat *:W | tee logcat.log > /dev/null 2>&1 &
>
> after_failure:
>   # - echo 'FAILURE'
>   # Check apt configuration: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#apt-configuration
>   # Comment out the lines below to show log about tests with app name customized on exports section.
>   - sudo apt-get install -qq lynx
>   - export MOD_NAME=yourappmodulename
>   - export LOG_DIR=${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/${MOD_NAME}/build/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/
>   - lynx --dump ${LOG_DIR}com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.html > myConnectedDevice.log
>   - lynx --dump ${LOG_DIR}com.android.builder.testing.html > myTesting.log
>   - for file in *.log; do echo "$file"; echo "====================="; cat "$file"; done || true
> ```

---

**Point 6** I added this only for completeness but seems useful, really i didn't try it. Ignore it now.

6. See linked response for: [Disable run tests from conflictive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24783102/1009132)

---

**Point 7** I really pointed the main reason of your problem if I'm not wrong and i think the script can be improved as i tried to explain when i opened the issue about the emulator.

7. You are using a bugged android-wait-for-emulator script, so your emulator is not ready when you begin your build. They fixed it but you are using the preinstalled outdated version.
   You can get the latest version using Shubham Chaudhary work around.

> ```
> # Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
> before_script:
>   - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
>   - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
>   - curl http://is.gd/android_wait_for_emulator > android-wait-for-emulator
>   - chmod u+x android-wait-for-emulator
>   - ./android-wait-for-emulator
>   - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
> ```

See: [second response here or use my script version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643444)

---

I delete **points 8 and 9** about tests and sdcard so I follow with the final response but you use the scard on your lib and we don't have permissions where is mounted by default.

---

**Point 10**

## **Issue 1: "ConnectedDevice > hasTests[] FAILED No tests found."**

See issue: [76249: Gradle should break if no tests are run](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76249)

See feature: [108410: Running tests with no test found will now break the build.](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/108410/)

As debug logs show [here](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/jobs/40613843#L5092) and a Google search about it, Issue 1 changed to

## **Issue 2: Ddmlib is too agressive with timeouts in Device.java**

See issue: [69735 -Ddmlib is too agressive with timeouts in Device.java](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69735)

See feature: 
[112780 - ddmlib: Allow install timeout to be specified as an env variable](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/112780/)

The names are very descriptive, can be useful, i thought it and waited for the feature but then i fixed my script and configuration issues and i dont need it. So issue 2 changes to:

## **Issue 3: "emulator is ready" message can be false.**

See issue: [2932 - New android-wait-for-emulator script needs be fixed](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2932)

See fix: [New android-wait-for-emulator fixed](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/commits/master/ci_environment/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator)

See alternative for custom it: [Original public domain script fixed and comments](https://github.com/ardock/iosched/blob/ttt-custom/scripts/wait_for_emulator.sh)

See recommended link for understand it: [Starting and stopping android emulators](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/)

we are running ARM version on x86 architecture without gpu-on and limited resources, I don't know if is it currently possible enable it on an VM image but probably x86 emulator versions will work better. We need install KVM and I didnt try it on Travis build servers or know if it's possible but I did it on my computer, following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation).

Emulator for android-21 needs more time to be ready and seems the important string was changed from `not found` to `device not found`. Travis team fixed it but the script redirects `stderr` to `stdout` and seems that adb server sends the misleading message `running`. They fixed it but you need the new version or an alternative as I do until VM images are updated.

If you do it and add logs to Travis output you'll see when your build has other issues as sdcard location or not. If you reload the job, it's possible that the emulator will be ready this time. You are running it on the background so it depends on what you are doing on your build. A litle change can do that Travis-ci kills a job if you don't manage the concurrency. Try to avoid downloads while the avd filesystem has been created. Remember that you use `&` so you are running it on a subshell and the resources are limited using a free plan. I didn't test other plans.

If you don't manage concurrency and resources, and design a good configuration script for your specific case, its's possible that sometimes your emulator is not ready, you see an error 137, you need a higher `INSTALL_TIMEOUT` and other random issues. You can try to reload the job and it's possible it works that time.

You can use `adb wait-for-device` to be sure emulator state is `device` before execute other heavy tasks, split the build, disable services and play with your resources. You can now use [cache](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/) for public repositories if you disable sudo. I'm testing it [here](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/builds/42187133). I'm currently not using the cache but the [container-based infrastructure](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/) seems works faster. All the jobs worked at the first time, less the 380.6 job. Issuing a `ShellCommandUnresponsiveException` as I think is your problem too, solved it reloading the job but probably I need improve my `.travis.yml` configuration file. So I looked for your issue, found my log and tried to improve this response.

I recommend you to use the original public domain script, fixed the string that changed and custom it for your case.

Comment: I have test for the project.i can run "gradle build connectedCheck --info" successfully on my computer,but failed to run the testcase when i push the project to the website Travis CI.i do not know why?

Comment: Are you running an emulator on your local machine when you test the project? Do you currently need it? You are running one on travis without test it so I think is the expected behavior now. If you don't need it, dont launch the emulator and no test will be performed.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that something is wrong when trying to install the app for test it. You can try 'gradle assembleDebug installDebug' and check logcat. If installation is correct, the problem is that you have not tests.

Comment: Another problem is that you use a bugged android-wait-for-emulator script, they'll update it soon. Currently when you read "emulator is ready" it is not (only running, needs more time). You can use Shubham Chaudhary work around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643444 or use mine.

Comment: ok,Ardock, i will try as what you told me later,Thank you.All Guys.

Comment: You are welcome. Travis configuration sample and build about installDebug, logcat, other wait-for-emulator etc. https://travis-ci.org/ardock/iosched/builds/41943256

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message.

After pulling my hair out for a while I ran it against an emulator with Android 4.4.2 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome issue by switching off my antivirus (in my particular case Kaspersky Internet Security)