# Gradle JUnit Espresso on Emulator connectedAndroidTest java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android, junit, gradle, android-emulator, android-espresso

I have a simple unit test for a static method and running them on Emulator.
(Goal is to run on cloud CI so I am testing on emulator.)

Gradle 2.2.1
Emulator Android 5.0

I use these steps on console.

1. android create avd --force -n test -t "android-21"
2. emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
3. adb wait-for-device
4. adb shell input keyevent 82 &
5. gradle clean installDebug
6. gradle connectedAndroidTest

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...

    androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger'
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
    }
}
```

The error log is

```
Tests on test(AVD) - 5.0 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError'

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[test(AVD) - 5.0] FAILED
No tests found.
```

What could produce this error ?

Comment: Can you post the full IncompatibleClassChangeError stacktrace from logcat? Also, Espresso 1.1 is known to have problems with API 21 devices ( although, I don't think that is the problem here )

Comment: You are probably right !!  I updated Espresso to 2.0 then error went away.

Comment: how to know which libraries we should add as dependencies and which group/module to exclude?

Comment: If this is a general question, that is totally depends on what your project needs and does not need.  In my specific example of espresso and dagger, I wanted to do simple espresso testing without any dependency injection (dagger) so I added espresso but excluded dagger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Brief response:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980452/what-causes-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror) seems a good link about `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError`. And If you try it on CI:

Emulator is not fully booted after wait-for-device, it's not ready for your tests and your app is not installed due a timeout, so there are no tests performed and the build fails as a new behavior added to alert you about it.

You can replace `adb wait-for-device` by a loop waiting for `stopped` state (fully booted) checking `adb -e shell getprop init.svc.bootanim` as [this script](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/scripts/wait_for_emulator.sh) in public domain does. [Further info here](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/).

Possible CI issue, Double Espresso was deprecated and Espresso 2.0 released:

**About CI and no tests found:**

I answered another question [but specific for Travis-ci here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084948/com-android-builder-testing-connecteddevice-hasteststestavd-5-0-failed). Similar error but due the script used was bugged. If you run `gradle installDebug --debug` you'll know more about the error (share the log here).

But running the same steps on a CI server, if I'm right, you'll see an InstallException caused by ShellCommandUnresponsiveException due a two minutes `INSTALL_TIMEOUT`. You can increase this value using an environment variable `ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=6` #minutes, but this is not your problem now.

If you are running it locally first, try it without `-no-window` (so you see it) or add `-no-boot-anim` (speed up it but is incompatible with wait-for-emulator script) or use `adb wait-for-device && sleep 300` (to be sure emulator is fully booted).

**About Espresso:**

[Double Espresso is deprecated](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso) because [Espresso 2.0 is now available](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/ReleaseNotes). Double Espresso is a pure Gradle port of Espresso 1.1 and Jake Wharton deprecated it when version 2.0 was published two weeks ago.

They [updated the wiki](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/w/list)  and [JavaDoc (they will move it to android.com)](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions#Javadoc).

[You can now use the Android Support Repository to download the latest version.](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions)

And Google [published new samples:](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing)

> Samples prerequisites: Android SDK v21, Android Build Tools v21.1.2,
>   Android Support Repository.
>
> These samples use the Gradle build system. To build a project, enter
>   the project directory and use the ./gradlew assemble command or use
>   "Import Project" in Android Studio. Use ./gradlew connectedCheck to
>   run the tests on a connected emulator or device.

**About Gradle tasks:**

From [Android tasks](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks) and [Running tests](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-tests) (Gradle Plugin User Guide):

- `assemble` The task to assemble the output(s) of the project
- `connectedCheck` Runs checks that requires a connected device or emulator.

Checks requiring a connected device are launched with the anchor task called `connectedCheck`. This depends on the task androidTest and therefore will run it. This task does the following:

- Ensure the app and the test app are built (depending on assembleDebug and assembleTest)
- Install both apps
- Run the tests
- Uninstall both apps.

**So I think:**

- It's a good moment to migrate to Espresso 2.0 (and avoid the [dependencies?](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso/blob/gradle/README.md) issue).
- You need to wait for emulator stopped state and I recommend [this link](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/) to understand it.
- You don't need specific `install*` tasks and can replace `assemble` by `build` (includes `lint`) and use `connectedCheck` (includes `connectedAndroidTest`).
- If there is more than one ABI installed, you'll need to choose one (and answer no): `- echo no | android create avd -f -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET -b $ANDROID_ABI`
- I would try their samples on the CI server you choose as a second step following your goal.

Comment: Thank you for the great info.  I am trying piece by piece.  Will update with results.

Comment: I updated Espresso and build was successful. Yet I would like to check out adb command as well.