# Android emulator on Travis CI showing com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[test(AVD) - 4.4.2] FAILED even though tests present

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-emulator, travis-ci

I've read through [com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests[test(AVD) - 5.0] FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084948/com-android-builder-testing-connecteddevice-hasteststestavd-5-0-failed) and I am having a very similar problem. Unfortunately, it's very difficult to discern what the actual solution to that problem *was*, given all of the discussion the solution author gave.

Essentially, I have the following .travis.yml file:

```
language: android

android:
  components:
  - build-tools-21.1.0
  - android-19
  - extra-google-google_play_services
  - extra-google-m2repository
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - addon-google_apis-google-19
  - addon-google_apis-google-21
  - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-19

before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-19 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - cat `which android-wait-for-emulator`
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script: ./gradlew clean build connectedCheck
```

When I push, and travis builds the appropriate .apk, I end up with the following log: http://pastebin.com/LVw5rG58

If I run `./gradlew clean build installDebug`, the build turns out fine, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with the timeout being too short in the `android-wait-for-emulator` script (also, it's using the newer version, I've checked - see the `cat which android-wait-for-emulator` command in the .travis.yml.

Additionally, I *do* have a single test in my source repository, and running `./gradlew clean build connectedCheck` on my local development machine (with a phone attached) works fine.

This just started happening since I updated gradle to 2.2.1 and updated the build tools to 21.1.0. However, I have another project using *the exact same* .travis.yml that *isn't* failing for some reason.

**Edit:**

My application has the following directory structure:

```
wagebase-android/
  - WageBase/
    - src/
      - androidTest/
        - java/
          - com.thisclicks.wagebase/  <- Test Sources
      - main/
        - java/
          - com.thisclicks.wagebase/ <- App sources
```

**Edit:**

It appears that if I run this on a local *emulator*, it also fails with the same error. I used the same configuration as in Travis, i.e.:

```
$ echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-19 --abi armeabi-v7a
$ emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
$ adb wait-for-device
$ ./gradlew connectedCheck
```

Comment: wait-for-device doesn't wait until emulator is fully booted. Try without -no-window and see it.

Answer (score 0):

About `Unable to find instrumentation target package: com.thisclicks.wagebase`:

If wagebase is a Project Library, check the first response, otherwise the second response here:
[unable-to-find-instrumentation-target-package-com-xyz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172636/unable-to-find-instrumentation-target-package-com-xyz).

> You have to create and setup an Application Project that depends on
>   the Library Project, in order to test the Library Project.
>
> When you create android test project remember to set good target
>   package
>
> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.example.test" <-------------------
> ```

If you run `gradle installDebug --debug` you'll know more about the error (share the log here), perhaps an [installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27703286/1009132). And you can show androidTest logs as I do [here, line 3848](https://travis-ci.org/ardock/android-testing/jobs/52175822#L3848)

```
cat ${TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/*/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/*
```

About dependencies, I think that you don't need `extra-google-google_play_services` included in `extra-google-m2repository`. You can check a working travis.yml file for google apis [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/.travis.yml).

```
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-21.1.2
    - android-21
    - addon-google_apis-google-21
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-addon-google_apis-google-21

before_install:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:21" --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a
```