# Travis.yml ./gradlew : Permission denied

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Using **Travis CI** for an existing Android project calling

```
$ ./gradlew build connectedCheck
```

I get this error:

```
/home/travis/build.sh: line 45: ./gradlew: Permission denied
The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" failed and exited with 126 during .
```

Answer (score 265, accepted):

It depends by the **exec-permission** to your unix `gradlew` script.

**It can be fixed using the command:**

```
git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
```

A little desciption to understand the problem.
First of all you can check your permissions using:

```
git ls-tree HEAD
```

You will see:

```
100644 blob xxxxxxxxxxx gradlew
```

As you can see the file has 644 permission.

**Fix it by setting the executable flag on your gradlew file changing it to 755:**

```
git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
```

Just commit and push the changes:

```
git commit -m "permission access for travis"

[master e80ab1b] gradlew permission access for travis
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 mode change 100644 => 100755 gradlew
```

A last check running git ls-tree again to see the change:

```
git ls-tree HEAD
```

You can see:

```
100755 blob xxxxxxxxxxxxx   gradlew
```

---

**Another way to solve this issue is to use:**

```
before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew
```

This kind of solution doesn't change the permission in your git repo, but just changes the permission runtime in the execution.

Comment: It worked. I did that in 'before_script:' in my case. Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason not to have the script checked in into git with the right permissions (I'd go for 1754). I abstain from adding additional `chmod` commands in build scripts because 1) it adds unnecessary complexity 2) won't work for other team members who clone the repo anew.

Answer (score 5):

```
script:
 - chmod +x ./gradlew build connectedCheck
```

Thanks all.
This code is available.
The key focus is on `chmod +x`

Comment: There are no such files as 'build' (well there is a directory perhaps) and 'connectedCheck' so this is unnecessary here. Better see the accepted answer