# Config travis.yml file in android project error

Tags: android, integration-testing, travis-ci

i just want travis ci check my project not have error (i don't have test case). But when i commit my code,travis ci always run fail or error (my project not have error). Someone can help me.

My travis.yml file content:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - build-tools-23.0.2
    - android-23
    - extra
  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'
  before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-19 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
  script: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

Chmod:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Try moving the last 6 lines (`before_script`..`script`) one indent back?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820638/travis-yml-gradlew-permission-denied